# xrpl4j - how to persist private key

Tags: java, private-key

I'm looking at the java coding samples for [xrpl4j](https://github.com/XRPLF/xrpl4j-sample/tree/main/src/main/java/org/xrpl/xrpl4j/samples)

All of them create new accounts to demo transfers, account info retrieval, etc.

This is done by first generating a random seed and then deriving the key pair, for example:

```
Seed sd = Seed.ed25519Seed();
KeyPair coldWalletKeyPair = sd.deriveKeyPair();
```

You can then get the private key with `coldWalletKeyPair.privateKey()`

I'm trying to persist the generated private key on the backend for future transactions but don't see any way to do this.

What is the proper way to persist the generated private key on the server (that generated it)?

I have tried serializing the private key but get an unserializable error and printing the private key in the console (of course) shows that it is redacted. I have also looked at the xrpl4j code to see what's going on under the hood to try to extract the private key but don't see the way.

Here's what I was doing to try to serialize the private key (I have left out the exception handling code):

```
    public byte[] serializeKeyPair(PrivateKey key) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream os =  new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        os.writeObject(key);
    
        byte[] res = bos.toByteArray();
    
        os.close();
        bos.close();
    
        return res;
    }
    
    
    Seed sd = Seed.ed25519Seed();
    KeyPair coldWalletKeyPair = sd.deriveKeyPair();
    
    byte barr[];
    barr = serializeKeyPair(coldWalletKeyPair.privateKey());
```

Here's the error message:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.xrpl.xrpl4j.crypto.keys.PrivateKey
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
```

Update:

Looking at xrpl4j.crypto.keys I managed to find another way in addition to @PeterMmm 's solution using Kryo:

```
Seed sd = Seed.ed25519Seed();
KeyPair coldWalletKeyPair = sd.deriveKeyPair();

UnsignedByteArray unsignedByteArr = coldWalletKeyPair.privateKey().value();
byte writeByteArr[] = unsignedByteArr.toByteArray();

FileTools.writeBytesToFile(writeByteArr, "file.bin");


byte readByteArr[] = FileTools.readFileToBytes("file.bin");
PrivateKey privateKey = PrivateKey.of(UnsignedByteArray.of(byteArr));
```

Comment: `I have tried serializing the private key but get an unserializable error` you should post the code and the error message.

Comment: Thanks, I added the code and the error message

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with [kyro](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) (I do not test if the read private key is usable)

```
Seed sd = Seed.ed25519Seed();
KeyPair coldWalletKeyPair = sd.deriveKeyPair();
System.err.println(coldWalletKeyPair.privateKey());

Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
kryo.setInstantiatorStrategy(new DefaultInstantiatorStrategy(new StdInstantiatorStrategy()));
kryo.register(PrivateKey.class);
kryo.register(UnsignedByteArray.class);
kryo.register(UnsignedByte.class);
kryo.register(ArrayList.class);

Output output = new Output(new FileOutputStream("file.bin"));
kryo.writeObject(output, coldWalletKeyPair.privateKey());
output.close();

Input input = new Input(new FileInputStream("file.bin"));
PrivateKey privateKey = kryo.readObject(input, PrivateKey.class);
input.close();

System.err.println(privateKey.equals(coldWalletKeyPair.privateKey()));
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! The read private key is correct and usable - it works for signing transactions.

Looking at xrpl4j.crypto.keys I managed to find another way and posted it above